# JSP Example to connect to MS SQL database using Tomcat

Tags: jsp, datasource, java-ee-5

I am trying to retrieve data using jsp but it showing
 Error:org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /databaseTest.jsp at line 13

My Code is:

```
<%@taglib  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSTL sql:query Tag</title>
</head>
<body>
   <sql:setDataSource var="ds" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
 url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/JSPTUTORIAL"
 user="root"  password="root"/>
    <sql:query dataSource="${ds}" var="result">
        SELECT * FROM Employees;
    </sql:query>
    <h4>Employee Table</h4>
    <table border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Employee ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}"/>
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${row.id}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${row.first}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${row.last}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${row.age}"/></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically code is correst. I past it in IDE and check. Maybe this code and /databaseTest.jsp is mismatch. Please, check it.

And I recommend not use  tag in real project. For example, in Spring you may create bean and set all data (login, password, etc) with dependency injection.